# Open .exe from python 3.8 main

Tags: python, subprocess, influxdb

I have the following code:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run("C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\Tool\\Database\\influxd.exe", close_fds=True, creationflags=0x00000010)
```

When I run it, the window just flashes and does not stay open.

When I run `subprocess.run("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe", close_fds=True, creationflags=0x00000010)`

everything is usable and stays open, so I guess it has something to do with the `influxd.exe` but I can't figure out what it is.

So how can I start an external program and make it independent from my Python program?

Comment: Try exec() https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Comment: Exec is for running python code not executables.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using os module.

[if the py file is within the same directory]
import os
os.system('start cmd /c "calc.exe"')

Comment: i read somewhere that subprocess should be prefered over os?

Comment: @chubaka: `os.system()` makes the exe _independent from my Python program_

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, i tried it, but same result. it starts but the window of InfluxDB does not stay open

Comment: @chubaka: That sounds more like a `influxdb` issue...

Comment: @MauriceMeyer i was suspecting this :/

Answer (score 0):

Use `os` module to run `.exe` file from python script. I ran `AnyDesk.exe` from my `E` drive using the following code.

```
import os

# path = "Path\to\your\exe\file"
path = 'E:\AnyDesk.exe'
os.startfile(path)
```

Comment: the outcome is the same as subprocess.run , influxd.exe is started, window shortly flashes but doesent stay open

Comment: But in my case, my AnyDesk application keeps open until I close manually. Your .exe file may be the issue. You can try with other applications to be confirmed.